Mirroring pkgs.tailscale.com with nginx fails, mirroring tailscale.com works
I am trying to mirror/reverse-proxy the package server pkgs.tailscale.com because that server is blocked at some locations.
For some reason I can easily mirror the regular tailscale.com website with this nginx config:
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name regularsite.myserver.net;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/chain.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://tailscale.com;

        # proxy_set_header Host $host; #This line cannot be used
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

But when I try to mirror the packages site in a similar way I just get a 502 error when going there :
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name pkgs.myserver.net;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/chain.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://pkgs.tailscale.com;

        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I tried a lot of different nginx settings but can't get it work.
Anyone that can knows what the problem is and how to fix it ? Preferably with Nginx but Apache or something else would also be fine.
Please try your answer first before answering, I already tried a lot of different configurations that (in theory) should work fine but didn't.
Just to be clear:

My server with nginx is able to connect to pkgs.tailscale.com over https, I checked it that with curl.
It's not really called myserver.net, that's just an example...

